# iOS: Create multiple dynamic views in interface builder

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

How do you make views with a dynamic height based on constraints?

Here is what I am trying to achieve:

[image: Current views]

I set the constraints for each view, **except** the **height** because that should be created **dynamically**. Is there a way without writing code to achieve this?

Comment: have you tried setting height to the aspect ratio of the main view height .

Comment: @sourav I selected all 3 views -> pin menu -> selected aspect ratio + height, however the middle view isn't the correct size

Comment: you might be setting its top and bottom fixed . remove those ...and if it shows error ...try suggested constants by xcode .

Comment: setting the height equally worked for me! thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1) set equal height for 3 views
>   2) set proportional height of one
>    view with superview

Comment: I selected all 3 views and set the height to "equal height". It does work now, however I didn't test yet if it will grow dynamically when content is put in (text). 

What do you mean with setting the proportional height?

Thanks for your quick reply btw!

Comment: set equal height with superview and then set multiplier to 0.20 if you want height 20% of superview